# Applying QGIS point cluster exception

Tags: qgis, symbology, spatial-cluster

I have applied a point clustering effect on a layer in QGIS. What I'd like to be able to do is cluster on all features except the ones that I have a NULL value in an attribute. I can Categorize on feature when zoomed in using the rendered Settings, but there doesn't seem to be an option for categorizing data when clustered.

Answer (score 1):

**Actually, the cluster renderer does support categorized styles.**

Next to the word `Renderer` there's a dropdown menu, where you can choose Categorized.

[image]

Under the Renderer type selection menu, click the button `Rendering Settings...` to access the normal layer style panel settings for a Categorized style.

[image]

Categorize by the field that has  values. Un-check the  category. Now the points with  values won't be displayed or included in any point clusters.

---

*Here's a workaround I wrote up before I realized that the cluster renderer supports categorized styles:*

**Apply a [Filter](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#query-builder) to the layer.**

Here's a point layer with a 20 mm cluster distance:

[image]

Apply a filter `"field" is not null"`

[image]

Now the points with  values in the field are excluded from the point clusters:

[image]

Comment: this doesn't categorize the Null feature, it just doesn't show or count it in the cluster. I did mention this rendered settings in my question, and that wasn't the solution. There would need to be a categorize option on both the rendered and the point cluster basically. Where the cluster symbol is categorized and the renderer symbol is catgorized.

Comment: the cluster renderer doesn't do that. you'll need to put the null features in a separate layer if you want them displayed separately.